# Changing web essentials output location for compiled less files

Tags: asp.net, web-essentials

How do I change the location where Web Essentials place my compiled Less css files?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Visual Studio 2013.

In your Visual Studio menu, there is `WEB ESSENTIALS` >> `Create Solution Settings`.

After the solution settings are created, a `WebEssentials-Settings.json` file will be generated in the `Solution Items` folder.

Go to the `Less` section of that file:

```
"Less": {
"CompileOnBuild": false,
"CompileOnSave": true,
"EnableChainCompilation": true,
"GenerateSourceMaps": true,
"MinifyInPlace": false,

"OutputDirectory": null,
// "OutputDirectory": "..\\..\\Content",

"ProcessSourceMapsForEditorEnhancements": true,
"ShowPreviewPane": true,
"StrictMath": false
},
```

Edit `OutputDirectory`. Change `null` into your target folder. Please note the `\` escape character is necessary. The `~\` prefix will not work.

---

Another place to look at is `TOOLS` >> `Options`. In the `Options` dialog, find `Web Essentials` group of settings. Under `LESS`, there is `Custom output directory`.

When editing in this dialog, no need for the `\` escape character. You can input `..\..\Content\CustomCss`.

---

If you happened to use Visual Studio 2012, there is some other application to help. For example, `koala`.

Here is the [link](http://koala-app.com/).

This [documentation](https://github.com/oklai/koala/wiki/Using-project-settings) shows how to change the output path.

Comment: I would mark this as the answer @archaictree. Thank you!